# Multi thread transactional Kafka producer and consumer with Spring Boot

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-transactions

I have a project which uses Spring Boot related project. I want to use the Transactional feature of Kafka consumer and producer in the project. I need to produce a lot of messages in Kafka as efficient as possible. So I need a multi-thread consuming and producing for this requirement. How can I use Spring boot for developing a multi-thread consumer and producer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `concurrency` [listener Boot property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.kafka.listener.concurrency).

```
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency
```

The topic must have at least as many partitions as the concurrency.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/#message-listener-container

Comment: Thanks. How can I have a multi thread transactional producer in Spring Boot?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; the producer is thread-safe; you can call it from any thread.